# Create Dialogflow Agent from scratch with C#

Tags: c#, dialogflow-es

According to the new DialogFlow API should be possible create an Agent from scratch with C#.

Now, documentation is not sufficiently complete to understand how to that: there's no specific about where do I get the project ID, how to invoke API through C# libraries, there nothing correlated with Google Cloud Platform.

I'm totally stuck because there's no linear path about it, that's why I'm here asking.

Comment: I don't *think* you can create an agent with the API directly. You can import an agent or restore one, but I don't see a CreateAgent method. In terms of "where do I get the project ID" - you should have that yourself, as you've presumably created the project. If you go to the GCP console, it should show you the project ID.

Comment: I did, with NodeJS I did.

Comment: Okay, so what API calls did you make? I'd expect the same API calls to work fine with the .NET client library too. I appreciate that we don't have a good step-by-step guide for working with Dialogflow from .NET, but the [reference documentation](https://googleapis.dev/dotnet/Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2/latest) will at least show what's possible.